# How to override preDispatch() function to add new open actions without redirect to login?

Tags: php, magento-1, overrides, customer-account

I want to add a new action for Customer AccountController and when I go do this action it redirects me to my login page. Here is my preDispatch() function with a new open action "download"

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    // a brute-force protection here would be nice

    parent::preDispatch();
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isDispatched()) {
        return;
    }

    $action = $this->getRequest()->getActionName();

    $openActions = array(
        'create',
        'login',
        'logoutsuccess',
        'forgotpassword',
        'forgotpasswordpost',
        'resetpassword',
        'resetpasswordpost',
        'confirm',
        'confirmation',
        'download'
    );
    $pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $openActions) . ')/i';

    if (!preg_match($pattern, $action)) {
        if (!$this->_getSession()->authenticate($this)) {
            $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
        }
    } else {
        $this->_getSession()->setNoReferer(true);
    }

}
```

If i delete parent::preDispatch(); it works but the login process doesn't work. If I keep the parent it redirects me to login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a tricky way,by using  that you can `overrider account controller`

### Modify overider controller code:

```
<?php
/* @ Purpose  ajax login
 * @ Author Amit Bera<dev.amitbera@gmail.com>
 * @ Module Devamitbera_Ajaxlogin
*/
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Customer').DS.'AccountController.php';
class Devamitbera_Ajaxlogin_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController{

   /*   Add new Action 
    */
    protected $_cookieCheckActions = array('loginPost', 'createpost','ajaxLoginPost');
   protected $defaultOpenActionList=
        array(
            'create',
            'login',
            'logoutsuccess',
            'forgotpassword',
            'forgotpasswordpost',
            'resetpassword',
            'resetpasswordpost',
            'confirm',
            'confirmation',
           'loginPost', 
           'createpost'
        );

    protected  $newOpenActionList= array(
            'ajaxloginPost'

        );




    /* Check customer authentication for some actions */
    public function preDispatch() {

         $currenAction=$this->getRequest()->getActionName();

        $pattern = '/^(' . implode('|', $this->newOpenActionList) . ')/i';

        if (preg_match($pattern, $currenAction)):

            $TempAction=  $this->getRequest()->setActionName('login');
         endif;

         parent::preDispatch();

         if($currenAction!=$this->getRequest()->getActionName()){
            $this->getRequest()->setActionName($currenAction);
        }

        if(!$this->getRequest()->isDispatched()){
            return;
        }

        if (!preg_match('/^('.$this->_getValidActions().')/i', $currenAction)) {

             if (!$this->_getSession()->authenticate($this)) {
              $this->setFlag('', 'no-dispatch', true);
             }
        } else {

             $this->_getSession()->setNoReferer(true);
        }

     }
     protected function _getValidActions(){
      return implode("|", array_merge($this->defaultOpenActionList, $this->newOpenActionList));
      }

}
```

At here for run  `my custom action` **ajaxloginPost**,
I have make a `temp action (login)` 
**$TempAction=  $this->getRequest()->setActionName('login');**.

at `preDispatch`, function .

Which make **override current action** as `login` whenever  `parent::preDispatch();` called